# Pulling multiple values of one column into a count structure with multiple counts

Tags: google-sheets, apple-numbers

I am looking to pull multiple counts into a mini-chart from a column with multiple values. I am trying to do it with one formula. It would end up looking something like this:

| ZIP codes | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 11238 | 4 |
| 46260 | 2 |
| 30201 | 1 |

Is there any way to make this with one formula?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look into `QUERY()`

Answer (score 0):

To be complete, you can use the `count()` operator and `group by` predicate in your `QUERY` statement to count occurrences of a column.

**Sample:**

Using `=QUERY(A1:B6,"select A,count(B) group by A",1)`

[image]

**References:**

[QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)